# Mutiple shortest match in HTMLwith regular expression using Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the content of 4 table of this HTML code http://catedral.prefeitura.unicamp.br/cardapio.php using the regular expressions in Python.
The tables starts with
"[\t\n\s]*"
and finish with
"</table>[\t\n\s]*</td>"
I am using the code follow:

```
menuSearchString = '<td align="left" valign="top">[\t\n\s]*<table width="[\d%]+" class="fundo_cardapio">([\s\S\d\t\n]+)<\/table>[\t\n\s]*<\/td>'
menus = re.findall(menuSearchString,page)
print menus
```

But I couldn't get the four matches of the tables. I think I am mistaking the greedy configuration and the "?" operator, I tried at the end but didn't work.

Comment: Did you tried `BeautifulSoup` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Part of your regex is being `greedy` which cause your regex to catch all the four tables in one match. All you have to do is to make this part `lazy` in order to get four matches.

Change this part of your regex:

```
[\s\S\d\t\n]+
```

To:

```
[\s\S\d\t\n]+?
```

Complete Code:

```
menuSearchString = '<td align="left" valign="top">[\t\n\s]*<table width="[\d%]+" class="fundo_cardapio">([\s\S\d\t\n]+?)<\/table>[\t\n\s]*<\/td>'
menus = re.findall(menuSearchString,page)
print menus
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I will check the BeautifulSoup library. Thanks by the tip.